# Laravel project routes not working when app is accessed over the network

Tags: laravel, routes, virtualhost, laravel-routing

when I access the application from same computer where wampServer is installed every thing works fine whether I access it using  localhost or Ip  of the computer but when I put wamp server online and access the same app from another computer using the Ip of the computer where wamp is installed routes doesn't work for me only root page is being accessed and if I click on any other link  I get 404 error

Here is **.htaccess** file in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteBase /laravel/itman/public/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

httpd-vhosts.conf file  in wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apache virtual host should point to the `public` directory for your laravel project.

e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/public"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/public">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: chaged it to <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/laravel/ItMan/public">  it still doesn't work

Comment: What do you have set for the DocumentRoot?

Comment: where should I check it ?

Comment: That is a second line in the virtual host configuration which is changed in the above answer. You affirmed that you changed the Directory line, did you also notice the change to the DocumentRoot line to include `/public`?

Comment: yes it is same , I noticed some issues like when I change the name of project folder, routes start working fine i.e if i change the folder name of "ItMan" to small letters like "itman"